# lowercase and remove punctuation from a csv

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a giant file (6gb) which is a csv and the rows look like so:

```
"87687","institute Polytechnic, Brazil"
"342424","university of India, India"
"24343","univefrsity columbia, Bogata, Colombia"
```

and I would like to remove all punctuation and lower the case of second column yielding:

```
"87687","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342424","universityofindiaindia"
"24343","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

what would be the most efficient way to do this on the terminal?

Tried:

```
cat TEXTFILE | tr -d '[:punct:]' > OUTFILE
```

problem: resultant is not in lowercase and tr seems to act on both columns not just the ssecond.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: done guys... literally does not matter, but whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using [xsv](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) and process substitution:

```bash
paste -d, \
    <(xsv select 1 infile.csv) \
    <(xsv select 2 infile.csv | sed 's/[[:blank:][:punct:]]*//g;s/.*/\L&/')
```

The sed command first removes all blanks and punctuation, then lowercases the entire match.

This also works when the first field contains blanks and commas, and retains quoting where required.

Comment: sorry to say, what does `xsv select 1 infile.csv` do?

Comment: can I get it to operate only on the second column of the csv? I would like the first column intact.

Comment: `xsv select` picks a single column, and `paste -d,` puts them back together; only the second column gets modified.

Comment: Does this snippet takes in account the file size of 6G? Sounds like all is done in memory opening 2 times the input file

Comment: @GillesQuenot I don't know what machine this runs on, and yes, if there's not much memory, it might become quite slow.

Comment: I have used this approach since I dont really know pearl. I think @GillesQuenot's answer is the correct one, but I am going to accept this one since I used this.

Answer (score 4):

##### With a [*real CSV parser*](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) in Perl, the robust/reliable way, using just one process.

As far as it's line by line, the 6GB requirement of file size should not be an issue.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;                   # harness
use Text::CSV;                              # load the needed module (install it)
use feature qw/say/;                        # say = print("...\n")

# create an instance of a new CSV parser
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ auto_diag => 1 });
# open a File Handle or exit with error
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "file.csv" or die "file.csv: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {     # parse line by line
    $_ = $row->[1];                         # parse only column 2
    s/[\s[:punct:]]//g;                     # removes both space(s) and punct(s)
    $_ = lc $_;                             # Lower Case current value $_
    $row->[1] = qq/"$_"/;                   # edit changes and (re)"quote"
    say join ",", @$row;                    # display the whole current row
}
close $fh;                                  # close the File Handle
```

##### Output

```
"87687","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342424","universityofindiaindia"
"24343","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

##### install

```
cpan Text::CSV
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/([^,]*,)([^ ,]*)[ ,]([[:alpha:]]+)/\1\L\2\3/;ta' input_file
"87687","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342424","universityofindiaindia"
"24343","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia
```

Comment: oh, where are you asking `sed` to only work on the second column?

Comment: @AJW `sed` is working on the second and third back reference with `\L` lowering the case of them.

Comment: I am sorry @Hatless what does `back reference` mean here? apologies if that sounds daft

Comment: This works only if there's no comma in the first field, though.

Comment: @AJW Have a look at this for a better understanding of back referencing https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html

Comment: @BenjaminW. Can you provide an example? It seems to remove commas anywhere except the one I have told it to keep

Comment: @HatLess For an input line like `"123,123","something, else"`

Comment: @BenjaminW. It still seems to work on my system.  Can you share the output you are getting please?

Comment: Sorry, example that breaks: `"87687,with Comma and blank","institute Polytechnic, Brazil"` gets the blanks removed in the first field and `Comma` is lowercased

Comment: It also breaks if there are multiple commas in the first field

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ah, I see. If that would be the case and OP clarifies, I will change my answer. But this would work `sed -E ':a;s/([^"]*",)([^ ,]*)[, ]+([[:alpha:
]]+)/\1\L\2\3/;ta' file`

Comment: You'll just keep bumping into CSV edge cases if you don't use a parser is my main point.

Answer (score 2):

Another `sed` approach -

```
sed -E 's/ +//g; s/([^"]),/\1/g; s/"([^"]*)"/"\L\1"/g' file
```

I don't like how that leaves no flexibility, and makes you rewrite the logic if you find something else you want to remove, though.

Another in `awk` -

```
awk -F'[", ]+' '
  { printf "\"%s\",\"", $2;
    for(c=3;c<=NF;c++) printf "%s", tolower($c);
    print "\"";
  }' file
```

This approach lets you define and add any additional offending characters into the field delimiters without editing your logic.

```
$: pat=$"[\"',_;:!@#\$%)(* -]+"
$: echo "$pat"
["',_;:!@#$%)(* -]+

$: cat file
"87687","institute 'Polytechnic, Brazil"
"342424","university; of-India, India"
"24343","univefrsity )columbia, Bogata, Colombia"

$: awk -F"$pat" '{printf "\"%s\",\"", $2; for(c=3;c<=NF;c++) printf "%s", tolower($c); print "\"" }' file
"87687","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342424","universityofindiaindia"
"24343","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

(I hate the way that lone single quote throws the markup color/format parsing off, lol)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using this `awk` solution, which should work with any version of `awk`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""} {
   gsub(/[^[:alnum:]"]+/, "", $2); $2 = tolower($2)} 1' file

"87687","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342424","universityofindiaindia"
"24343","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

**Details:**

- We make `","` input and output field separators in `BEGIN` block
- `gsub(/[^[:alnum:]"]+/, "", $2)`: Strip all non-alphanumeric characters except `"`
- `$2 = tolower($2)`: Lowercase second column

Answer (score 2):

One `GNU awk` (for `gensub()`) idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
      { $4=gensub(/[^[:alnum:]]/,"","g",tolower($4)) }
1'
```

This generates:

```
"87687","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342424","universityofindiaindia"
"24343","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `ruby`. Edited the data to show only the second field is modified.

```
% ruby -r 'csv' -e 'f = open("file"); 
    CSV.parse(f) do |i| 
      puts "\"" + i[0] + "\",\"" + i[1].downcase.gsub(/[ ,]/,"") + "\"" end'
"8768, 7","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342 424","universityofindiaindia"
"243 43","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

Using `FastCSV` gives a huge speedup

`gem install fastcsv`

```
% ruby -r 'fastcsv' -e 'f = open("file"); 
    FastCSV.raw_parse(f) do |i| 
       puts "\"" + i[0] + "\",\"" + i[1].downcase.gsub(/[ ,]/,"") + "\"" end'
"8768, 7","institutepolytechnicbrazil"
"342 424","universityofindiaindia"
"243 43","univefrsitycolumbiabogatacolombia"
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
"8768, 7","institute Polytechnic, Brazil"
"342 424","university of India, India"
"243 43","univefrsity columbia, Bogata, Colombia"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E s'/("[^"]*",)/\1\n/;h;s/.*\n//;s/[[:punct:] ]//g;s/.*/"\L&"/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Divide and rule.

Partition the line into two fields, make a copy, process the second field removing punctuation and spaces, re-quote and lowercase and then re-assemble the fields

---

An alternative, perhaps?

```
sed -E ':a;s/^("[^"]*",".*)[^[:alpha:]"](.*)/\L\1\2/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following **GNU** `awk` code using `match` function of it. Using regex `(^"[^"]*",")([^"]*)(".*)$` in `match` function which will create 3 capturing groups and will store the value into arr and respectively I am fetching the values of it later in program to meet OP's requirement.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/(^"[^"]*",")([^"]*)(".*)$/,arr){
   gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]+/,"",arr[2])
   print arr[1] tolower(arr[2]) arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do so in PHP.

Note: PHP will not output double quotes unless needed by the first column. The second column will never need double quotes, it has no space or special characters.

```
$max_line_length = 100;
if (($fp = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fp, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[1] = strtolower(preg_replace('/[\s[:punct:]]/', '', $data[1]));
        fputcsv(STDOUT, $data, ',', '"');
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```